# Using ImageJ in hadoop and get awt headless exception

Tags: java, hadoop, awt, imagej

I've been trying to build an image processing app using ParticleAnalyzer of ImageJ 1.45 / ImageJA. the algorithm has been tested perfectly on my mac, but when I shipped the runnable jar onto the hadoop cluster, it kept throwing the awt headless exception. I've looked up online and tried these approaches, but none of them fixed the problem!

http://imagej.1557.n6.nabble.com/Headless-ImageJ-td3699125.html

Also, I tried to catch the exception at the spot, but then I found that the  ParticleAnalyzer didn't actually run (it kept returning 0 particle which is wrong. my mac gives non-zero results!)
. Here is the java code section, followed by the exception I copied from the hadoop log.

If anyone has a successful story using ImageJ on Hadoop, could you please give me a solid code example?

Thanks in advance.

```
try{
            ParticleAnalyzer pa = new ParticleAnalyzer(options, measurements,
                rt, THRES_AREA, 10000, 0, 1);

            pa.setup("victor", result);
            pa.run(result.getProcessor());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("engine: awt error!");
    }

java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:431)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at ij.gui.GenericDialog.<init>(GenericDialog.java:87)
    at ij.plugin.filter.ParticleAnalyzer.showDialog(ParticleAnalyzer.java:265)
    at ij.plugin.filter.ParticleAnalyzer.setup(ParticleAnalyzer.java:220)
.....
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Comment: Did you install Xvfb on your Hadoop machines?

Comment: I'm not admin on cluster so I can't ... Any other way?

Comment: See also this [article](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:technical:how_do_i_run_imagej_without_a_graphics_environment_headless).

Comment: I've read it and tried this one. same exception!  http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=faq:technical:how_do_i_run_imagej_without_a_graphics_environment_headless

Answer (score 1):

The [Fiji project](http://fiji.sc/) has put in a substantial effort to make headless operation more feasible with ImageJ, though there are still some limitations.

The three major solutions are:

1. Run Fiji using the `--headless` flag
2. Use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)
3. Rewrite the script or plugin in question

That said, in this case, since the "script or plugin in question" is actually ImageJ's built in Particle Analyzer, the `--headless` approach should work.

Please see the article on [headless mode](http://fiji.sc/Headless) for full details.